# JS Bootstrap get curent text from dropdown (without actions)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying get current text from dropdown:

```
function dtChange(){
  var elem = document.getElementsByName("ul.dropdown-menu li a");
  var name = elem.innerHTML;
```

but name is always 'undefined':

```
<div class="dropdown" name="dpt1">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">ATT
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="company" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
```

What's wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function dtChange(){
  var elem = document.getElementsByName(".dropdown-menu li a");
  var name = elem.innerHTML;
```

or

```js
function dtChange(){
  var elem = document.getElementsByName("ul li a");
  var name = elem.innerHTML;
```

hope to help you